# Extra-Official vs Non-Official vs Unofficial

Tags: word-usage, disambiguities

What's the difference between them?

I understand they are pretty much the same in terms of synonym.
Are they better suited for some specific scenarios?

I think, in some cases, those three could be used interchanged, but there are other cases that one or another would be better for disambiguation purposes.

I have being using them like this:

- Unofficial: Nobody gave authorization or confirmation. Normally when I want to denote use or source of something.
- Non-Official: Outside official knowledge. Normally when I want to point something that is outside the approval of the company or a government or any entity (for instance, non-official statements, non-official car...).
- Extra-Official: When I'm pointing to something that is outside a predefined scope. For instance, there are a set of rules or approved official things (information, software, group of people... anything) but the thing is not part of that scope.

Is there a better definition or use of those three words?

Edit: Based on [the following definition](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjah-3p_-zSAhUCeCYKHRx7BpgQFgggMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webster-dictionary.org%2Fdefinition%2FExtra-official&usg=AFQjCNEtipJ4NlrI5f30vBZDxe2492FCZA&sig2=TPTCvqiheh2WWBAsaGXYwQ&bvm=bv.150475504,d.eWE), my understand is that "Extra-Official", depending on the scenario, could have a significant difference than the other two.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the use of "extra-official" in standard American English. You are using the other two correctly.

Comment: @MarkHubbard , thanks, that's quite a relief! Regarding the Extra-official, [here is a link](http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/Extra-official) that may clarify its usage.

Comment: Thank you! I'm always glad to learn something new. In formal writing, the hyphenated "extra-official" would be correctly understood, but in *speech* it could sound sarcastic, since informally, *extra* can mean "especially." For example, to say out loud "His actions were extra-official" could mean either. In those situations, it might be better to say something like "His actions were not officially sanctioned" to insure clarity. Just a thought.

Comment: Yep... that's my understand too. I think "extra-official" brings a lot of ambiguity to the phrase. That's why I raised that question here. At work I already explained that we should go with Non/Un instead of Extra.